# Excel VBA JSON POST request with curl

Tags: json, excel, vba, curl

I am trying to sent request using JSON in Excel VBA, the request go trough however all I got is a blank reply.

Here is the sample request:

https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/requests

```
    Sub QPX()

    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sJson As String
    Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument
    Dim sEnvlength As Integer
    Dim responseText As String

    Dim ApiKey As String
        ApiKey = "MyAPIkey"

    Set ObjHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    sURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=" & ApiKey

         sJson = sJson & " {"
         sJson = sJson & "   ""request"": {"
         sJson = sJson & "   ""slice"": ["
         sJson = sJson & "     {"
         sJson = sJson & "        ""origin"": ""LHR"","
         sJson = sJson & "        ""destination"": ""VIE"","
         sJson = sJson & "        ""date"": ""2014-12-24"""
         sJson = sJson & "      }"
         sJson = sJson & "    ],"
         sJson = sJson & "    ""passengers"": {"
         sJson = sJson & "      ""adultCount"": 1,"
         sJson = sJson & "     ""infantInLapCount"": 0,"
         sJson = sJson & "      ""infantInSeatCount"": 0,"
         sJson = sJson & "      ""childCount"": 0,"
         sJson = sJson & "      ""seniorCount"": 0"
         sJson = sJson & "    },"
         sJson = sJson & "    ""solutions"": 20,"
         sJson = sJson & "    ""refundable"": false"
         sJson = sJson & "  }"
         sJson = sJson & "}"


    ObjHttp.Open "POST", sURL, False

    ObjHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"


    ObjHttp.send (sJson)

    xmlDoc.LoadXML (ObjHttp.responseText)
    MsgBox responseText

    End Sub
```

Their guid is saying:

Then execute the following command from within the same directory as the above request.json file. (As explained in Prerequisites, you must first obtain an API key.)

```
curl -d @request.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=your_API_key_here
```

How can I implement curl in my coding?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What about `MsgBox ObjHttp.responseText`? Also blank?

Comment: MsgBox ObjHttp.responseText solved the issue. Now I need to find out how to phrase the response in meaningful format :)

Comment: Hm, JSON is a meaningful format. Your problem now is "How to parse JSON with VBA?" Good question for google.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar research (posted as answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21655764/205034)) a month ago. You can try [VBA JSON](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html) with [TCP library](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?453366-Counting-Particular-Letter-Occurrences-in-a-String).

```
Sub main()
  Dim tcp As New TCPClient
  Dim ok As Boolean

  ok = tcp.Connect("192.168.1.63", 6666)
  If Not ok Then
      Debug.Print "Error Connecting"
      Exit Sub
  End If

  tcp.Send "{""Country"":""France"",""Salaries"":{""Peyton Manning"":800.0,""Blaine Gabbert"":200000.0},""Name"":""Amazon.net""}"
  tcp.CloseConnection

End Sub
```